# Default Upload Location needs matrix field and entry info... How?

Tags: assets, matrix, image, upload

I have a `towns` entry with a matrix field: `townAlbums`.

This matrix field has just one block type: `photoAlbum`.

This one block type has two basic text fields (the important one being `albumName` and one asset field for uploading images to the gallery: `albumPhotos`.

I want the Default Upload Location for this matrix subfield `albumPhotos` to be dynamic, taking both the parent entry slug (slug of the town entry) and the name of the album: `albumName`. I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

**Desired url:**

`http://sitename.com/uploads/towns/town-slug/album-name/filename.jpg`

What should I be entering for my Default Upload Location?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your desired URL is:

```
http://sitename.com/uploads/towns/town-slug/album-name/filename.jpg
```

The the "Upload Location" for the setup you described would be something like:

```
towns/{owner.slug}/{albumName}/
```

I'm assuming `towns` is just hard-coded since you're referencing `town-slug` in the next segment.

Comment: This did create the right directory structure, but the uploaded photos end up getting saved in the root `uploads/` directory, not the `towns/town-slug/album-name/` path it successfully created.

Comment: Weird... something else must be going on. Tested locally and it worked.

Comment: Not sure what has changed since. Maybe something in one of the recent Craft updates?? In any case, I just tried your suggestion again and can confirm it's working on my end now. Thanks!!